# How to run MongoDB and Mongo-express with docker-compose?

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose

I try to run MongoDB and Mongo-express by Docker-compose. I use following config:

```
version: '3'

services:
    mongo:
        image: mongo
        environment:
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${MONGO_ROOT_USER}
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=project
    mongo-express:
        image: mongo-express
        environment:
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongo
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT=27017
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN=false
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_DATABASE=admin
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_USERNAME=${MONGO_ROOT_USER}
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_PASSWORD=${MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=${MONGOEXPRESS_LOGIN}
            - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=${MONGOEXPRESS_PASSWORD}
        depends_on:
            - mongo
        ports:
          - "8080:8081"
```

and .env file:

```
MONGO_ROOT_USER=devroot
MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD=devroot
MONGOEXPRESS_LOGIN=dev
MONGOEXPRESS_PASSWORD=dev
```

After `docker-compose up` mongo-service is running, but mongo-express fails. I see error in logs:

```
mongo-express_1  | Welcome to mongo-express
mongo-express_1  | ------------------------
mongo-express_1  | Mongo Express server listening at http://0.0.0.0:8081
mongo-express_1  | Server is open to allow connections from anyone (0.0.0.0)
mongo-express_1  | Database connected
mongo-express_1  | Connecting to admin...
mongo-express_1  | TypeError: db is not a function
mongo-express_1  |     at /node_modules/mongo-express/lib/db.js:114:53
mongo-express_1  |     at Array.forEach (native)
```

What I do wrong? Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

it works in my mac. If you delete docker-compose containers and rebuild, maybe it will work. I added my files. Only i changed mongo-express port.

.env

```
MONGO_ROOT_USER=devroot
MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD=devroot
MONGOEXPRESS_LOGIN=dev
MONGOEXPRESS_PASSWORD=dev
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
    mongo:
        image: mongo
        environment:
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${MONGO_ROOT_USER}
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=project
    mongo-express:
        image: mongo-express
        environment:
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongo
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT=27017
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN=false
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_DATABASE=admin
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_USERNAME=${MONGO_ROOT_USER}
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_PASSWORD=${MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=${MONGOEXPRESS_LOGIN}
            - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=${MONGOEXPRESS_PASSWORD}
        depends_on:
            - mongo
        ports:
          - "8888:8081"
```

Docker Version

```
Client:
 Version:           18.06.0-ce
 API version:       1.38
 Go version:        go1.10.3
 Git commit:        0ffa825
 Built:             Wed Jul 18 19:05:26 2018
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          18.06.0-ce
  API version:      1.38 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.3
  Git commit:       0ffa825
  Built:            Wed Jul 18 19:13:46 2018
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     true
```

Comment: it is not working now, the error is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'listDatabases' of undefined`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60087244/mongoexpress-shows-cannot-read-property-listdatabases-of-undefined-error

Answer (score 10):

This problem comes when your database uses a volumes configuration, but mongodb and mongo-express doesn't share a network configuration.
This worked perfectly for me:

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  db:
    container_name: mongo-dev
    image: mongo:4.2
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=auth
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
    networks: 
      - mongo-compose-network
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes: 
      - ./data:/data/db
  
  mongo-express:
    container_name: mongo-express
    image: mongo-express
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks: 
      - mongo-compose-network
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongo-dev
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=pass
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=tribes
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
    volumes: 
      - ./data:/data/db      

networks:
  mongo-compose-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: why are you setting your mongo-express volume to same as your db? isn't that going to dumpl files from both to the same location?

Answer (score 5):

Some updates in new verion of mongo-express, the accepted solution doesn't work any more, especially you need fix this issue

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'listDatabases' of undefined
```

### Tips

Do remember, if you adjust the setting, restart it with option `--force-recreate`.

```
docker-compose up --force-recreate -d
```

Here is the docker-compose.yml I am using currently.

```
version: '3'

services:
    mongo:
        image: mongo:${MONGO_TAG}
        environment:
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${MONGO_ROOT_USER}
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=project
    mongo-express:
        image: mongo-express
        environment:
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongo
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT=27017
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN=true
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_DATABASE=admin
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=${MONGO_ROOT_USER}
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=${MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=${MONGOEXPRESS_LOGIN}
            - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=${MONGOEXPRESS_PASSWORD}
        links:
            - mongo
        ports:
          - "8081:8081"
```

Answer (score 4):

Running it like this just worked for me maybe it helps you

```
      mongoex:
        image: mongo-express
        environment:
        - ME_CONFIG_OPTIONS_EDITORTHEME=ambiance
        - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=database
        - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT=27017
        - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN=false
        - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_DATABASE=admin
        ports:
        - "8081:8081"
        links:
        - database
      database:
        image: mongo:latest
        command: --smallfiles
        ports:
          - "27017:27017"
```

good luck and regards!

Answer (score 4):

Mongo-express changed the user and pass ENV keywords:

OLD:

```
- ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_USERNAME=${MONGO_ROOT_USER}
- ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_PASSWORD=${MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD}
```

NEW:

```
 - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=${MONGO_ROOT_USER}
 - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=${MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD}
```

reference: 
https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo-express

Answer (score 3):

Although this post is bit old. I would like to share the docker-compose.yml that worked for me.

The below spins up a mongoDB instance and mongo-express.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  mongo_db:
    image: mongo:4.2.12
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - /C/Mine/mongoData:/data/db

  mongo_express:
    image: mongo-express:0.54.0
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_OPTIONS_EDITORTHEME=default
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongo_db
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT=27017
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN=true
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_DATABASE=mydb
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=root
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=rootpassword
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - mongo_db
```

Comment: are the '-' necessary. the docker documentation for the mongo image does not use them: https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo

Comment: @mike01010 Its been a year so which ever '-' you are referring to could be obsolete. You may try with out it. If it works you may stick to it.

Comment: yeah, most dont seem to be necessary any longer

Answer (score 3):

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
```

Save and get into the folder and run docker-compose up. Now mongo will run at port http://localhost:8081/.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is run `docker-compose up -d` in directory with docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mongo:
    image: "mongo:3-stretch"
  mongo-express:
    image: "mongo-express:latest"
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
```

And then open http://localhost:8081/ in your browser.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are still having this issue... Or in case someone else is going absolutely crazy trying to figure out why none of this works...

Running docker-compose up --force-recreate

Doesn't recreate the container completely (not sure why) - it DOES look like it did, but I figured out that it wasn't recreating the container's data (databases!) when I got into the DB without Auth, and a collection that I created an hour ago was still there.

I had run the above command, and also 'docker image rm mongo' as well as removing the mongo-express (Not needed)

The problem is I had to do a 'docker container list'  to see the two containers I had (one for Mongo by itself and one for Mongo with Mongo-express - not sure which I needed to delete, but I deleted them both...)

Once I did that, and did the 'up' your configuration pulling the values from the .env file worked fine - it did the INITDB... and set the Admin passwords correctly in the database!

So, if you EVER created it with any configuration to test it, you will have a container that it is reusing the data for (I think it doesn't recreate that to avoid data loss - I mean, 99.9% of the time you just want to recreate the PROGRAM part, not the data - otherwise you would lose your databases.)

Killed a couple hours figuring this one out...

Comment: I would also note that for all those people whose answers basically said:  turn off auth, it works fine!  That isn't answering the OP's question.

Comment: Well, I added ports: and - 27017:27017 to the mongo service (container), and I'm able to connect just fine to it with RoboMongo (T3something now), but the Mongo-Express part connects with the Admin just fine, but when you login it throws an Auth error.   It doesn't look like it is worth using this image for anything anyway.  They have an Auth, but no way to logout, and it doesn't seem to work.  I'm not really sure why one would use that instead of just running mongo and a real too.  Anyway, I hope this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

This is very useful things but same time unstable. You need find out your own way How to write `docker-compose.yml` For me It's was works something like that

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mongo:2.6.12
    container_name: app_db
    volumes:
      - store:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  mongo-express:
    container_name: mongo-express
    links:
      - 'db:mongo'
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
    environment:
      - 'ME_CONFIG_OPTIONS_EDITORTHEME=ambiance'
      - 'ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=user'
      - 'ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=pass'
    image: mongo-express
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar issue

```js
mongo-express  | (node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongo-dev:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.20.0.2:27017
```

Added the below line to recover from this, because docker sometimes takes time to expose the mongo port 27017 and mongo-express  fails to connect and stops, with `restart: always` mongo-express container reconnect's to mongo port 27017
each time when it crashes

```yaml
mongo-express:
    container_name: mongo-express
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
```