# Docker image not able to connect with public IP address

Tags: docker

I am new in docker and my docker image not acessable using server public ip. I have create a AWS ec2 instance and create two different docker image `mongo-express`, `mongo` and `nginx` but I am not able to access these images with my server pulic Ip (34.XXX.XXX.X) address all three images run under same network below share the network inspect

```
[
{
    "Name": "mongo-network",
    "Id": "f770fd5305d755f792506dd4a302a5ad9cfda1a934432711bf2222cb854208f4",
    "Created": "2021-08-09T05:34:21.364086783Z",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": {},
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": false,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {
        "6adee8e06887adb2ba5ce5d6d213fa60af759b9a029317c94cd1d576a4982c5a": {
            "Name": "mongo-express",
            "EndpointID": "4aba503e4a1a6c6339f4c58ac98b66f2dc41d1a244f1b5a78c6c3a72fd60a4d8",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
            "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "d5acca8e26db1f0c48d57f6bc880c88bfe14c0b0999b4c108a033a492c6ead5c": {
            "Name": "mongo",
            "EndpointID": "0d0fc6a53182b4ecb05cd396192cfc7677780389c9fb724ad036dfebd182f44f",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
            "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
    "Options": {},
    "Labels": {}
}
```

]
[image]

Error Log
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your ERROR log, it's clear that you have some mismatch in ENV configuration of the `mongo-express` container. Did you run it with required ENV variables described here https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo-express? (look at Example section)

I think it will be better to stop your containers, prune images and volumes with `docker system prune -a --volumes` and start from scratch. Also I'll suggest to run it with help of docker-compose. Try to use docker-compose and env file described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950331/3034558

Comment: yes I have open all require port for everone in security group but why i am not able to connect mongo-express its 8081

Comment: Are you sure that you are trying to connect to `http://pubilc-host-ip:8081`? Try to debug mongo-express container logs with `docker logs --tail 50 --follow --timestamps mongo-express`. Maybe there is a problem with connection between mongo and mongo-express.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the command I think its version issue above share the error log please take a look and share your valuable comments on this again thanks for giving your time

Comment: Thanks again @czende its working now i am using docker-compose.yml file