# MongoDB Compass can't connect to Docker hosted Mong-rs

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, mongodb-compass

I saw several questions similar to mine, but I wasn't able to solve my problem based on what I've seen so I am writing my own.

I have a Docker-compose.yaml file where we have this configuration:

```
mongo-rs:
    image: mongo:4.4.21
    restart: always
    container_name: mongo-rs
    command: ["--replSet", "rs0", "--bind_ip_all", "--port", "30001"]
    volumes:
      - ~/.docker/mongo-rs/data/:/data/db
    ports:
      - 30001:30001
    healthcheck:
      test: test $$(echo "rs.initiate({_id:'rs0',members:[{_id:0,host:\"mongo-rs:30001\"}]}).ok || rs.status().ok" | mongo --port 30001 --quiet) -eq 1
      interval: 10s
      start_period: 30s

  mongo-express-rs:
    image: mongo-express:0.54.0
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8086:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongo-rs
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT: 30001
```

In Docker Desktop I can see that the container is up and running. I am able to connect to Mongo Express `http://localhost:8086/` but when I open MongoDB Compass I am unable to connect. I tried several connection strings but I am getting error no matter what I am using:

[image]

Given this how can I connect to the Mongo instance in Docker?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run MongoDB and Mongo-express with docker-compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47901561/how-to-run-mongodb-and-mongo-express-with-docker-compose)

Comment: @SebastianLiebscher This is not the problem in my specific case. Actually I was able to figure this out. The problem was in the connection string. It should look like this `mongodb://localhost:30001/?directConnection=true` Using `directConnection` is specific for Mong-rs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case we use Mongo-rs instead of the standard MongoDB. This is mainly when we need the to transactions working with Mongo. However this requires a change it the connection string which becomes something like this:

`mongodb://localhost:30001/?directConnection=true`

In my case this was all I need to get things up and running an I hope that this will save some time to other people getting the same issue as me.